# Logging In Issue - Umbraco 6 - I am sure I have the right password

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco6, umbraco-blog

Just took over an umbraco 6 project from another developer, the first thing I wanted to do was to get it running locally on my computer.

So I restored the DB back up file, created a local website in IIS, and then changed the connection string.

When I browse the website it works no problems, I can surf the site, click diffrent pages, etc etc. All good.

However when I try to log in with the password (which I'm pretty sure is correct) I can't.

Now when you log in with a user name and password that is not correct, you get red lines around the password and username field.

However when I type in the correct password, there is no red lines around the feilds, they just clear and I don't log in.

Never seen this before not sure what the problem could be, I could start trying to hack the dabase to reset the password, but I think that is pointless as I am sure I have the right password.

Any ideas, why I can't login?

Comment: Just had a look at the server where I copied the files and the database and have noticed that...
the whole website is SSL....

Maybe this is why I can't log in, how do I recreate SSL on my own local machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK fixed it........

I had to change this in the web config to **false**

```
<httpCookies requireSSL="true" />
```

I guess because I have copied the files from a live server that use SSL I have to have the same set up locally or change this value in the webconfig file.

Hope this helps someone else.